# Как добиться фиксированного времени вставки и получения из коллекции?

Tags: java, коллекции, java-hashmap

Здравствуйте уважаемые коллеги, я столкнулся с заданием в котором необходимо:

Создать справочник-коллекцию которая должна иметь методы:

1. `boolean insert(T key, V value)`;
2. `V get(T key)`;
3. `boolean delete(T key)`;
4. Реализовывать итератор.
5. Внутренняя реализация должна использовать массив.
6. **Нужно обеспечить фиксированное время вставки и получения.**

И моя проблема в том, что я не понимаю, каким образом, может быть фиксированное время вставки, и получения. Ведь если я буду использовать массив, то мне все равно придется пробегаться по ключам до совпадения. И даже если мне удасться соорудить хеш-таблицу на основе связанной структуры, все равно время `get`, для последнего и первого элементов будет отличаться (вариант с использованием деревьев исключен, т.к. еще не проходили).

Помогите пожалуйста с идеей как это принципиально должно работать чтобы соблюдались все поставленные передо мной условия задачи. p.s. только пожалуйста, не пишите код, я хочу сам, мне нужно именно идею уловить, как оно должно работать.

Comment: Для множества произвольных объектов не получится реализовать вставку/извлечение **всегда** за `O(1)`, так как в общем случае всегда возможны коллизии. В том же `HashMap` в худшем случае (когда все элементы будут в одной корзине), извлечение будет за `O(n)`, если корзина реализована в виде связного списка и за `O(log n)`, если корзина реализована в виде сбалансированного дерева.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> И моя проблема в том, что я не понимаю, каким образом, может быть фиксированное время вставки и получения.

В общем случае, вставить/извлечь элемент за константное время не получится. При отсутствии коллизий можно вставить/извлечь элемент за `O(1)`, но коллизии (для неограниченного множества объектов) возможны **всегда**. В случае наличия коллизий вставить/извлечь элемент можно за `O(n)` (в случае использования связного списка) и за `O(log n)` (в случае использования сбалансированного дерева).

> Ведь если я буду использовать массив, то мне все равно придется пробегаться по ключам до совпадения

Если Вы будете использовать массив с *обычной* адресацией, то да, извлечение элемента по ключу будет возможно за `O(n)`. Но Вы можете реализовать хэш-таблицу, в которой, в *лучшем случае* извлечение элемента будет осуществляться за константное время.

> И даже если мне удасться соорудить хеш-таблицу на основе связанной структуры, все равно время `get`, для последнего и первого элементов будет отличаться

Да, будет различаться. И константным оно будет только если искомый элемент будет первым в корзине.

> вариант с использованием деревьев исключен, т.к. еще не проходили

Даже в этом случае время извлечения элемента не будет всегда константным.

> Помогите пожалуйста с идеей как это принципиально должно работать чтобы соблюдались все поставленные передо мной условия задачи

Вам нужно реализовать простенький `HashMap`, но 6-й пункт будет выполняться только лишь частично. Иногда вставка/извлечение элемента будет выполнятся за константное время, а иногда за линейное или за логарифмическое (это зависит от структуры данных, которая будет использована для разрешения коллизий).

Основная идея `HashMap` заключается в том, что для расчета индекса элемента в массиве (номера корзины) используется хэш-код ключа. В самом простом случае, номер корзины можно получить как:

```
int index = HASH_CODE % TABLE_LENGTH;
```

где:

- `HASH_CODE` – хэш-код ключа элемента;
- `TABLE_LENGTH` – размер массива, который используется для хранения элементов (количество корзин).

Для разрешения коллизий можете использовать, например, метод цепочек (он используется в `HashMap`), либо открытую адресацию (в этом случае элемент с совпадающим хэш-кодом располагается в ближайшей следующей корзине).

Почитайте как устроен `HashMap` – Вам нужно реализовать подобную структуру данных.

А вообще, Ваш вопрос очень общий и объемный. Лучше поделите его на несколько вопросов, тогда можно будет дать какой-то конкретный ответ.